# Why does gcc -march=native select broadwell on a coffeelake cpu?

Tags: gcc

Running on an [i5-8600K](https://ark.intel.com/products/126685/Intel-Core-i5-8600K-Processor-9M-Cache-up-to-4_30-GHz) cpu which has Coffee Lake microarchitecture. [This page](https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/intel/microarchitectures/coffee_lake#Compiler_support) says I should use `-march=skylake` on GCC. However `-march=native` option seems to select Broadwell:

```
$ gcc -march=native -Q --help=target | grep march
  -march=                           broadwell
```

My GCC version is 7.3.0.

Which of these architectures should I use to compile my code?

Comment: Can you check with a snapshot of gcc-8? A snapshot of gcc-7.4? In any case, the reason is likely that your CPU is too recent, and gcc's bugzilla would be a better place to report this.

Comment: @MarcGlisse It seems to select skylake in gcc 8. Thanks!

Comment: Good. If this hasn't been backported to gcc-7.4, it may still be worth asking for it.